# Enable ORDS for a Schema in Oracle sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to configure REST service on oracle. I already installed and launched ORDS and now want to enable schema but i don't see this function when I right-click on my database connection

Enable ORDS for a Schema

[image: Enable ORDS for a Schema].

Should I configure or install something more?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your install was less than successful.

On connection, we check for this to see if the UI should surface the 'Enable REST' context menu:

```
SELECT *
  FROM(SELECT substr(
         ords.installed_version,
         1,
         6
     )AS installed_version
       FROM dual
      )
 WHERE installed_version NOT IN(
    '3.0.4.',
    '3.0.3.',
    '3.0.2.',
    '3.0.1.',
    '3.0.0.'
)
```

What version of ORDS did you install?
What version of SQL Developer are you running?

Also, if you do

```
SELECT *
  FROM user_ords_repoversions;
```

Do you get anything back?

Finally - did you connect to a pluggable? We don't let you REST enable a schema in the Container Database (CDB)

Answer (score 0):

I install v18.4.0.354.1002, db v18c, sqldev 18.3 I don't get anything back from these queries.

This is log from installation.

```
C:\Users\ZPSA\Desktop\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\jdk\jre\bin\java -Duser.language=pl -Duser.country=PL -jar C:\Users\ZPSA\Desktop\ords-18.4.0.354.1002\ords.war configdir C:\Users\ZPSA\Desktop\ords_conf
lut 25, 2019 5:42:02 PM  
INFO: Set config.dir to C:\Users\ZPSA\Desktop\ords_conf in: C:\Users\ZPSA\Desktop\ords-18.4.0.354.1002\ords.war
C:\Users\ZPSA\Desktop\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin>
C:\Users\ZPSA\Desktop\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\jdk\jre\bin\java -Duser.language=pl -Duser.country=PL -jar C:\Users\ZPSA\Desktop\ords-18.4.0.354.1002\ords.war install --parameterFile C:\Users\ZPSA\Desktop\ords-18.4.0.354.1002\params\sqldev_ords_params.properties simple
Your database connection is to a CDB.  ORDS common user ORDS_PUBLIC_USER will be created in the CDB.  ORDS schema will be installed in the PDBs.
Root CDB$ROOT - create ORDS common user 
PDB PDB$SEED - install ORDS 18.4.0.r3541002 (mode is READ ONLY, open for READ/WRITE)

lut 25, 2019 5:42:10 PM  
INFO: reloaded pools: []
lut 25, 2019 5:42:10 PM oracle.dbtools.installer.InstallerCDB log
INFO: 

lut 25, 2019 5:42:10 PM oracle.dbtools.installer.InstallerBase log
INFO: Installing Oracle REST Data Services version 18.4.0.r3541002 in CDB$ROOT
lut 25, 2019 5:42:10 PM oracle.dbtools.installer.Runner log
INFO: ... Log file written to C:\Users\ZPSA\ords_cdb_install_core_CDB_ROOT_2019-02-25_174210_00922.log
lut 25, 2019 5:42:12 PM oracle.dbtools.installer.Runner log
INFO: ... Verified database prerequisites
lut 25, 2019 5:42:12 PM oracle.dbtools.installer.Runner log
INFO: ... Created Oracle REST Data Services proxy user
lut 25, 2019 5:42:12 PM oracle.dbtools.installer.InstallerBase log
INFO: Completed installation for Oracle REST Data Services version 18.4.0.r3541002. Elapsed time: 00:00:01.648 

lut 25, 2019 5:42:13 PM oracle.dbtools.installer.InstallerBase log
INFO: Installing Oracle REST Data Services version 18.4.0.r3541002 in PDB$SEED
lut 25, 2019 5:42:13 PM oracle.dbtools.installer.Runner log
INFO: ... Log file written to C:\Users\ZPSA\ords_cdb_install_core_PDB_SEED_2019-02-25_174213_00297.log
lut 25, 2019 5:42:13 PM oracle.dbtools.installer.Runner log
INFO: ... Verified database prerequisites
lut 25, 2019 5:42:14 PM oracle.dbtools.installer.Runner log
INFO: ... Created Oracle REST Data Services schema
lut 25, 2019 5:42:14 PM oracle.dbtools.installer.Runner log
INFO: ... Created Oracle REST Data Services proxy user
lut 25, 2019 5:42:15 PM oracle.dbtools.installer.Runner log
INFO: ... Granted privileges to Oracle REST Data Services
lut 25, 2019 5:42:18 PM oracle.dbtools.installer.Runner log
INFO: ... Created Oracle REST Data Services database objects
lut 25, 2019 5:42:27 PM oracle.dbtools.installer.Runner log
INFO: ... Log file written to C:\Users\ZPSA\ords_cdb_install_datamodel_PDB_SEED_2019-02-25_174227_00183.log
lut 25, 2019 5:42:28 PM oracle.dbtools.installer.Runner log
INFO: ... Log file written to C:\Users\ZPSA\ords_cdb_install_apex_PDB_SEED_2019-02-25_174228_00836.log
lut 25, 2019 5:42:30 PM oracle.dbtools.installer.InstallerBase log
INFO: Completed installation for Oracle REST Data Services version 18.4.0.r3541002. Elapsed time: 00:00:17.309 

lut 25, 2019 5:42:31 PM oracle.dbtools.installer.InstallerCDB log
INFO: Completed CDB installation for Oracle REST Data Services version 18.4.0.r3541002.
Total elapsed time: 00:00:20.112 

lut 25, 2019 5:42:31 PM oracle.dbtools.standalone.ModifyUser createUsers
INFO: Created user: ords_admin in file: C:\Users\ZPSA\Desktop\ords_conf\ords\credentials
lut 25, 2019 5:42:31 PM oracle.dbtools.standalone.ModifyUser createUsers
INFO: Created user: ords_servlet in file: C:\Users\ZPSA\Desktop\ords_conf\ords\credentials
2019-02-25 17:42:31.041:INFO::main: Logging initialized @25023ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
lut 25, 2019 5:42:31 PM  
INFO: HTTP and HTTP/2 cleartext listening on port: 8080
lut 25, 2019 5:42:31 PM  
INFO: Disabling document root because the specified folder does not exist: C:\Users\ZPSA\Desktop\ords_conf\ords\standalone\doc_root
2019-02-25 17:42:31.662:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.z-SNAPSHOT; built: 2018-05-03T15:56:21.710Z; git: daa59876e6f384329b122929e70a80934569428c; jvm 1.8.0_181-b13
2019-02-25 17:42:31.684:INFO:oejs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2019-02-25 17:42:31.684:INFO:oejs.session:main: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2019-02-25 17:42:31.684:INFO:oejs.session:main: node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
lut 25, 2019 5:42:31 PM  
INFO: Configuration properties for: |apex||
db.hostname=192.168.3.199
db.password=******
db.port=1521
db.servicename=orcl
db.username=sys as sysdba
resource.templates.enabled=true

lut 25, 2019 5:42:31 PM  
WARNING: *** jdbc.MaxLimit in configuration |apex|| is using a value of 10, this setting may not be sized adequately for a production environment ***
lut 25, 2019 5:42:31 PM  
WARNING: *** jdbc.InitialLimit in configuration |apex|| is using a value of 3, this setting may not be sized adequately for a production environment ***
lut 25, 2019 5:42:32 PM  
INFO: Configuration properties for: |apex|pu|
db.hostname=192.168.3.199
db.password=******
db.port=1521
db.servicename=orcl
db.username=ORDS_PUBLIC_USER
resource.templates.enabled=true

lut 25, 2019 5:42:32 PM  
WARNING: *** jdbc.MaxLimit in configuration |apex|pu| is using a value of 10, this setting may not be sized adequately for a production environment ***
lut 25, 2019 5:42:32 PM  
WARNING: *** jdbc.InitialLimit in configuration |apex|pu| is using a value of 3, this setting may not be sized adequately for a production environment ***
lut 25, 2019 5:42:33 PM  
INFO: Oracle REST Data Services initialized
Oracle REST Data Services version : 18.4.0.r3541002
Oracle REST Data Services server info: jetty/9.4.z-SNAPSHOT

2019-02-25 17:42:33.041:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3835c46{/ords,null,AVAILABLE}
2019-02-25 17:42:33.041:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler@1dde4cb2{/i,null,AVAILABLE}
2019-02-25 17:42:33.057:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@3c0be339{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1, h2c]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2019-02-25 17:42:33.058:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @27040ms
```

Comment: Please don't post an answer containing information which should be added to the question. Instead, **edit the question** using the `edit` button just below the tags. You have the ability to edit your own questions. Thanks.